# How to deserialize Json object which contain control character using Dojo.fromJson

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am using Dojo.fromJson to convert json string to javascript object, but throw exception. Because, there are control characters such as `',\n,\r` in the json string.

How can I solve this problem in dojo? convert json string to javascript object, even if there are control characters.

I use Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert C# oject to json data. Json Object: `{"name":"'\"abc\n123\r"}` then, I use `Dojo.fromJson(' {"name":"'\"abc\n123\r"}')` to convert json data to javascript object.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please shown an example of an input string and the code you use.

Comment: When generating those json data the controls characters inside strings must be escaped. You could write some evil parser to transform those "json" data into valid json data.

Comment: I use Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert C# oject to json data.
Json Object: {"name":"'\"abc\n123\r"}
then, I use Dojo.fromJson(' {"name":"'\"abc\n123\r"}') to convert json data to javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Problem, i believe is the double-quote which should be escaped by triple backslashes. You can use "native browser JSON decode" as searchterm for "dojo fromJson" synonym.

Without knowing my way around C# - I havent tested but i believe following should work:

```
string c_sharp_name = "'\"abc\n123\r";
// C#Object.name
c_sharp_name = c_sharp_name.
  replace('"', '\\"'). // maybe add a slash on serverside
  replace('\n', '\\\n').
  replace('\r', '\\\r');
```

since

- while this fails:
- {"name":"'\"abc\n123\r"}     // your single backslash
- this would work:
- {"name":"'\\\"abc\\\n123\\\r"}   // working triple backslash escape